# _ArrayBuffer crash

Tags: ios, swift

It have a crash that I can't reproduce it on my phone. I call this function in `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform`.

Here is my code:

```swift
public var arrayLessons: [NotesLessonDataModel] = []

...


func addLessonIfNeeded(lesson: NotesLessonDataModel) {
        
    if lesson.isValid() == false { return }
        
    for item in self.arrayLessons {
        if lesson.id == item.id {
            return
        }
    }

    self.arrayLessons.append(lesson)
}


...

DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: array.count) { (index) in
            
    requestGroup.enter()
    
    // Callback function
    
    self.addLessonIfNeeded(lesson: item)
    requestGroup.leave()

}
```

Here is the firebase crash report:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x383c88 _swift_release_dealloc + 24
1  Pocket Papers                  0x111594 specialized _ArrayBuffer._consumeAndCreateNew(bufferIsUnique:minimumCapacity:growForAppend:) + 4339750292
2  Pocket Papers                  0x91bdc PPNotesManager.addLessonIfNeeded(lesson:) + 4339227612 (<compiler-generated>:4339227612)
3  Pocket Papers                  0x927f4 closure #1 in PPNotesManager.getLessonsFromSections(_:exam:completion:) + 146 (PPNotesManager.swift:146)
4  libswiftDispatch.dylib         0x5558 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Int) -> () + 28
5  libswiftDispatch.dylib         0x5584 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@unowned Int) -> () + 32
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x4860 _dispatch_client_callout2 + 20
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x18d7c _dispatch_apply_invoke_and_wait + 160
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x18790 dispatch_apply_f + 728
9  libswiftDispatch.dylib         0x54c8 static OS_dispatch_queue.concurrentPerform(iterations:execute:) + 284
10 Pocket Papers                  0xa5e7c closure #1 in NoteViewController.requestLessonDetails() + 161 (PPNotesManager.swift:161)
11 Pocket Papers                  0xc240 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4338680384 (<compiler-generated>:4338680384)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x2a84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x481c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x7968 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 756
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x15fe0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 388
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x167d8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3768 _pthread_wqthread + 216
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xa74c start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: At a guess I would say that you're running into a race condition on the `arrayLessons` variable.   One thread is in the middle of reallocating the array to add an item, when another thread tries to access the array.  You probably need a synchronization strategy for `arrayLessons`

Comment: Thanks, @ScottThompson I updated my code using synchronization and submit a new build. I will review the firebase crash reporting in a few days.